# sequelize js - eager loading creates objects with all fields as null

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

seqeulize model include (eager loading) creates nested objects EVEN IF they dont exist in the database, resulting in an object with all fields as null.
for example:

poll.server.model.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    var Poll = sequelize.define('Poll', {
            // fields
        },
        {
            associate: function(models){
                Poll.hasMany(models.Comment, {foreignKey:'poll_id', foreignKeyConstraint: true})
            }
        }
    );

    return Poll;
};
```

comment.server.model.js

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    var Comment = sequelize.define('Comment', {
            // fields
        },
        {
            associate: function(models){
                Comment.belongsTo(models.Poll, {foreignKey: 'poll_id'})
            }
        }
    );

    return Comment;
};
```

this is the function at the controller (in short)

```
db.Poll.findAll({include:model:db.Comments}).then(function(polls){
    res.jsonp(polls);
});
```

when i load a poll which has comments that exist in the DB, everything is working well. the problem is, when i load a poll without comments, i still have an array of comments, containing a single object with all fields as null

```
$$hashKey: "2LA"
comment_date_inserted: null
comment_date_updated: null
comment_fingerprint: null
comment_id: null
comment_parent_id: null
comment_text: null
comment_text_raw: null
comment_title: null
comments: Array[1]
poll_id: null
poll_option_id: null
user: Array[1]
user_id: null
```

the same is true for any other eager loading i make (notice the comments: Array[1] -> subcomments (which dont exist) and user: Array[1] -> object with all fields empty )

my questions are:
1 - why is this happening?
2 - am i doing something wrong / what am i doing wrong in the include part?
3 - should i / is it possible to have a condition in the include, for example if all fields are null dont include?

Comment: Which version of sequelize are you using ?

Comment: sequelize 2.0.5 / sequelize-mysql latest

Comment: this still seems to be an issue in sequelize 3.2.0

Comment: sequelize 4.38.0 and still a issue